# Issue comparing char's in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class wheresCarlson
    {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    public wheresCarlson()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        print("Where is Carlson?");
        print("Enter the date below to find out: (MM/DD/YYYY)");

        String date = sc.next();

        print(date);

        int value = date.charAt(4);

        if (value == 1) {
            print("Carlson's alarm didn't go off");
        }


    }


    public String print(String x)
    {
        System.out.println(x);

        return x;
    }

}
```

I am attempting to have an if/else run depending on what the date is, however, I cannot get this if/else to run with the input from scanner.  Is it not possible to compare characters in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034580/comparing-chars-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with Scanner but a slight problem with your code:

```
int value = date.charAt(4);
```

See here what your are trying to do is saving character to integer, therefore your if condition is never executed:

```
char value = date.charAt(4);
if(value == '1')
{...}
```

This should work.

Comment: The `'1'` character already is its own ASCII value. There is no conversion.

Comment: the code doesen;t work as he is trying to compare a char to an int, the change i proposed yields the result

Comment: @user207421 No, the ASCII value of '1' is 49

Answer (score 2):

You are interpreting something wrong. When getting the char of your date string the char is a "letter". Each char is represented by a decimal value. Take a look at the ASCII table. The value of the char "1" would be 49.
So you might want to compare either chars or parse the char to the int representation.

Compare chars:

```
if(value == '1'){...}
```

Cast to int then compare:

```
int intValue = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(4));
if(intValue == 1){...}
```

Comment: ASCII is a distinct character set and encoding that doesn't apply here. `char` holds a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is one of several encodings for the Unicode character set. See [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) representation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the char value, not the int value

`char value = date.charAt(4);`

then compare as a char

`if (value == '1') {`