# Using if/else statements against a Range

Tags: java, string, if-statement, range

The code I'm using is supposed to identify whether something is a digit, letter, etc and kick back the proper response.

I was getting errors that I couldn't use booleans on char so I translated the input char into a string.

Now I'm using the code below, but I can't use math operators on a string. I need to use char as input b/c program should be able to recognize letters and special characters.

Could I instead use a range?  Ie '1-9' and 'a-z'? I've tried it in several capacities ([1-9], "[1-9]", etc.), but I keep getting error messages. My guess is that I'm formatting it incorrectly.

```
package charreader; 

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Charreader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

Scanner newScan = new Scanner(System.in); 

//prompt for input and read it
System.out.println("Enter a character.");
char ch = (char)System.in.read();

//convert ch to string
String st = String.valueOf(ch);

if (st >= 1 && <= 9 )
{
    System.out.println("Digit");
}

else 
{
   System.out.println("Not a digit.");
}
```

The only thing I HAVE gotten to work is:

```
if (st == '0')
{
    System.out.println("Digit");
}

else 
{
   System.out.println("Not a digit.");
```

But I don't want to run the entire program like that. It would be clunky and generally bad practice.

Comment: You may want to include the exact errors you got, instead of just saying that you got errors. Also note that strings cannot be compared using `>=` and `<=`, nor can you compare a string to a char like you do (your second example cannot work contrary to your statement that you have gotten it to work).

Comment: Java doesn't have a built-in "range"

Comment: In any, case this is probably a duplicate of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034580/comparing-chars-in-java

Comment: You can easily use `Character.isDigit(ch);` to check

Answer (score 3):

In java we have built-in methods for that. Like these for characters :

```
char a = 'b';
Character.isDigit(a);
Character.isLetter(a);
```

even for an string you can use these method :

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
   try {
       int number = Integer.parseInt(str);
       return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       return false;
   }
}
```

EDIT : if you do not want to use Character class, we can do like this :

```
char ch = 'r';
if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
    System.out.println("alphabetic");
else if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    System.out.println("digit");
else
    System.out.println("none");
```

Comment: Using isDigit etc would make everything infinitely easier, but said prompts are strictly forbidden. (Sorry, should have mentioned that earlier)

Comment: Be aware that `isDigit()` also recognizes digits in other scripts (see the documentation)

Comment: so you can use if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'). and if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'), I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

It look like you just want to check if it's a positive digit.
You could use:

```
Character.getNumericValue()
```

this returns a -1 if it is not a digit or -2 if it is not a non negative int. So something like this:

```
char ch = (char)System.in.read();
if(ch.getNumericValue() > 0){ 
//"is a pos int"
} else { 
//"not a pos int
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this will also recognize numeric values from other scripts, contrary to the original range of '1' - '9' in the question. For example `Character.getNumericValue('Ⅼ')` returns 50 (Ⅼ is unicode roman numeral fifty (U+216C))

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in order to achieve the result. 
I will suggest you to have a read to [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) article as they explain how to use regex in Java.

Alternatively instead of converting char to string, you can convert char to int directly.
example:

```
char c='1';  
int a=Character.getNumericValue(c);
```

the function getNumericValue will return you a number. You need to keep in your mind that it will throw an error if the char is not a number.

One last thing to keep you mind is that in Java you use single quote ('/') for String and double quote ("/") for char.

Answer (score 0):

Ranges don't exist in Java. 
Instead use:

```
if ((symbol >= 'A' && symbol <= 'Z') || symbol == '?') {
// ...
}
```