# Create user interface with while loop

Tags: java

I currently have an assignment on creating a user interface with while loop, here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Part3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome dear user!");
        System.out.println("Would you like to:");
        System.out.println("a) sum gain");
        System.out.println("b) exit");

        System.out.print("Option: ");
        String optionString = input.next();
        char option = optionString.charAt(0);

        while (option == ("a")){
            System.out.println("Helo");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with the while loop, when I compile, it is error say a bad operand types for binary operator. I'm new to java so can you guys help me out with this. Thanks a lot

Comment: `"a"` is a string. You cannot compare a character to a string.

Comment: so do you know how can I change this?

Comment: change "a" to 'a'

Comment: You can compare characters to characters. Learn how characters look in Java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034580/comparing-chars-in-java

Comment: Also, your while loop is an infinite one as currently written.

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea how can I make it just print only 1 "Helo"

Comment: It work perfectly now, thank you a lot

Comment: Replace the `while` with an `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be facing the following issue:

```
Part3.java:14: error: incomparable types: char and String
        while (option == ("a")){
```

Because you're trying to compare a **char (option)** and a **String ("a")**. So do use **'a'** instead of **"a"**.

Even when you'll resolve this issue, it seems that your code will stuck into a infinite loop when user will choose option a.

If you wanna print it only one time use break; statement inside loop.

```
while (option == ("a")){
            System.out.println("Helo");
            break;        
}
```

Comment: nice, it work now. Thank you. However, because the condition is always true so it become an infinite loop, do you any idea how to make it just print only 1 "Helo"?

Comment: Use a break; statement.
Edited the answer.